# nohup in shell script does not work in debug mode with set -x

Tags: bash, nohup

The script `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

nohup echo hello &
```

When run `./test.sh`, output is

```
+ nohup echo hello
appending output to nohup.out
```

But when ssh is setup and run `ssh localhost ./test.sh`, output is nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine.

The command is executed, but you won't see the output, by that time the ssh connection was already terminated.

Check `nohup.out`, it will show that the command was indeed executed.

Comment: there is no `nohup.out` when the script is executed remotely via ssh.

Comment: try something like `nohup echo hello >/tmp/mytest &`